# How to override spring context place holder of dependency jar?

Tags: java, spring

I have the below configuration in xml of an maven dependency jar.

```
context:property-placeholder location="file:/dir/project.properties"/>
```

Unfortunately I can't create that folder in my machine and can't modify dependency code too. So when I am running the parent app, I want to override the location of properties file or provide external properties file.

Both parent and child are  developed using Spring Core. (It's not Spring Boot). Parent is War and child is jar.

Comment: And have a stern talking to to whoever hard-coded such a ridiculous location.

Comment: I am using Mac, Catalina version. I can't create directory in root folder. So I have to overwrite. I tried to set spring.config.location  through command line but no use.

Comment: Can we override dependency property location from parent?

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring Context lifecycle, if it uses Spring Cloud Context, the Spring application first loads configuration from `bootstrap.properties`, then starts and then loads `application.properties` (in your case `project.properties`).

You can add to the project dependencies the Spring Cloud dependency. Specifying classpath (or using default `config` folder) you can have properties in another place.

Comment: Didn't get you exactly. Could you please help me with sample code to understand better

Comment: Can you configure your dependencies? I mean maven or grade ...
If yes, just add

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

After that you can place bootstrap.properties in classpath and Spring App first will load it.

Comment: Oh.. That's it.. No more configuration. Just adding dependency will change context Hirarichy. Let me try